# Is it a good practice to hot swap java code in production?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, hotswap

We have a huge spring based monolith Java app that takes ~30 minutes to deploy. I recently found out the hotswap capabilities coming with the JDK quite helpful in development although it can only hotswap method body.

The official docs from oracle suggests below [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/enhancements1.4.html#hotswap)

> Organizations deploying long running servers wish to be able to fix bugs without taking down the server.

Is it recommended to do it in production?. What are the pros and cons of it?

Comment: What kind of infrastructure are you running on? Can you boot an additional instance and switch traffic?

Comment: We are using kubernetes and tomcat as servlet container. I guess we can do that. But many processes usually keep running in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't.

Pro:
No deploymemt time.

Con:
Never, NEVER do a hot swap on a production system. Only if you are 100% sure about everything, but no one is 100% sure.
I would recommend to never practice this task.
Saved time isn't worth more than safety.
What if your code has side effects you so not know?

Please don't.

Fix the bugs and then create a release.

Please Take a look at this Image:
https://rapidbi.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Project-management-triangle.png.webp
You can only pull in TWO sides of the triangle.

Kind regards

Comment: Thank you. I understand there would be some side effect, but don't exactly know what kind. Depends on how smart JVM with hotswap is I guess, but I can imagine it causing serious problems during runtime that we will never be able to debug if issues arise.

Comment: There could be any side effects you can (and can not) think of. From false business logic in the code because everything must be done fast, to "errors" the compiler/JVM does not recognize. And think about caches, caches with wrong cached data. I ran into cache problems several times while doing "easier" stuff than hot swapping. Wrong cached older versions of classes, wrong cached dependencies, and so on. And yes, you are right: You will never be able to debug this. And even more to think about: What if the hot swap breaks the prod system? Before hot swapping a backup is recommended (IMO)!